# Not sure what this ruby method does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The below method is some code I inherited and it's supposed to remove parameters from a url but it's breaking with the following error:

> ArgumentError: the input of URI.decode_www_form must be ASCII only
>   string
>       /home/fatman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/uri/common.rb:969:in
>   `decode_www_form'

```
    def self.removeUnnecessaryGetParams(url, removeParams = ["s"], whiteListParams = nil)
    uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)

    #Get rid of UTM parameters & S parameters
    if(uri.query != nil)

        if(whiteListParams != nil)
            cleanKeyVals = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).reject{|k, _| !whiteListParams.include?(k)}
        else
            cleanKeyVals = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).reject{|k, _| k.start_with?("utm_") or removeParams.include?(k)}
        end

        uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(cleanKeyVals)
    end

    return uri.to_s.split("#")[0].chomp("?")
end
```

1). My Question is, how exactly is this method working? Not sure what the lines are doing that assign to `cleankeyVals` (my ruby knowledge shortcomings).

2). How to fix this ASCII only string issue?

Comment: Have you looked at the string that causes this error? You're trying to give it non-ASCII characters apparently.

Comment: The naming conventions, the use of `!= nil`, and other quirks suggest this was not written by someone who really gets Ruby. Also worth updating Ruby if you get a chance. Keep current to avoid security problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `uri.query` appears to be a Ruby Hash object, `#reject` will reject entries in the object that meet the predicate described within the block. The first sieve removes keys not in the whitelist, the second rejects based on keys that start with `utm_` or keys that are within `removeParams`.
2. Simply do `url.gsub!(/\P{ASCII}/, '')` on the line immediately following the function definition. This regex will strip out non ASCII characters for you. (As an aside `#gsub!` modifies the original while `#gsub` returns a copy, this is a common Ruby convention that you will see as you start to explore the language more)

Comment: immediately following the function definition? Not sure what adding url.gsub!(/\P{ASCII}/, '') immediately following function def would do.?

Comment: It will strip out all non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your data and parse correctly, try this

```
URI.parse(URI.encode('http://example.com/?йцу=1'))
=> #<URI::HTTP http://example.com/?%D0%B9%D1%86%D1%83=1>
```